# multilingual dictionary for ubuntu with IPA

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, dictionary

I am looking for a multilingual dictionary for ubuntu with these features

```
1. IPA
2. English
3. Japanese
4. Korean
```

I have found several but none of them have IPA.

```
OS: Ubuntu 11.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/) and download the relevant Babylon dictionaries from [their web site](http://www.babylon.com/free-dictionaries/). You will have to download the .exe file of and use 7Zip to extract the .bgl (dictionary) file from it.
The dictionaries also include the IPA.

Comment: I am trying to download the dictionaries from Babylon from the link you gave but all I'm getting is Babylon9_setup_dict.exe. how can I download them.

Comment: @TaylorBioniks I modified the answer with further details.

Comment: I have extracted the before mentioned exe and the .bgl file is nowhere to be seen

Comment: Babylon just made all dictionaries downloadable in BGL format